# com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater sometimes remaining in memory (hprof dumps)

Tags: android

I'm inspecting memory trying to find eventual memory leaks via hprof dumps.

I find that sometimes when I leave an activity via back button (which would finish the activity), the activity would still remain in memory but it would only have two GC root, which don't seem to be very 'strong' though.

This is my activity flow / the way I click and test:

A, B, C being activities.

**1) A -> B -> (back to) A**

**2) do a hprof dump** with the following result:

***B is still in memory***, the only elements in GC root of B activity are:

com.myapp.android.activity.directory.B

- mContext of **com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater**

  - mLayoutInflater of android.app.ContextImpl [Stack Local]

    - [local variable] of java.lang.Thread [Thread]  "main"
- mOuterContext **of android.app.ContextImpl [Stack Local]**

  - [local variable] of java.lang.Thread [Thread]  "main"

(Thread "main" seems to be the UI thread)

continue from A:

**3) A -> C -> (back to) A**

**4) do a hprof dump** with the following result (as expected):

**B is not in memory anymore**, C is not in memory anymore, only A

**Now my question is:
where does this PhoneLayoutInflater come from / why does it remain in memory when I return from B to A, but it would be gone after went further on to C and return back to A.**

Obviously the PhoneLayoutInflater is for inflating views, I'm aware of it's purpose. I just don't see why it would be kept in memory via the GC root from the main UI thread.

When I check the GC roots of above listed

> [local variable] of java.lang.Thread
>   [Thread] "main

it would have the following:

- mUiThread of com.myapp.android.activity.main.**A** [Stack Local]

  - ....

    - this$0 of android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ControlledInputConnectionWrapper **[JNI Global]**

The way I call the activities B and C from A is via a regular `startActivity(intent)`

**Why would the main UI thread of activity A somehow be related and referenced from activity B?**

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html may be relevant.

Comment: thanks for the link, but I've read this already many times. there's no reference to UI thread of another activity, also I don't know where "this$0 of android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ControlledInputConnectionWrapper [JNI Global]" come from. That's the strange thing here.

Comment: I have the same problem with the phoneLayoutInflater. In the past I have used reflection to flush out such memory oddities in android (usually relating to lists) but I don't know what the hell causes this or what I could reflection to null without f'ing up my app. Going to add a bounty to this.

Comment: @MathiasLin After 5 years (: Did you find the reason of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing but I'm still not pleased that I'm using reflection to fix this. Anyone??

```
public static boolean ReleaseActivityContext(Context context)
{                       
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);     
    Class<?> i = inflater.getClass();

    try 
    {    
        Field f = i.getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mContext");
        f.setAccessible(true); // prevent IllegalAccessException
        f.set(inflater, null); // can cause IllegalAccessException
        return true;    
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return false;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I used Eclipse MAT to analyse hprof, I spent over 8 hours and finally I have found out that there are some simple rules to follow.

> Do not keep long-lived references to a
>   context-activity (a reference to an
>   activity should have the same life
>   cycle as the activity itself)
>
> Try using the context-application
>   instead of a context-activity.
>
> Avoid non-static inner classes in an
>   activity if you don't control their
>   life cycle, use a static inner class
>   and make a weak reference to the
>   activity inside.

Follow these steps:
[image]

Then click...
[image]

you can see the reason of objects staying in memory
[image]

Now revise your code and see why there are some references exists when there is no need of them to exist. then on back key press nullify those references and viola .. world will look beautiful again :)

Comment: I am using Eclipse MAT for analyzing memory.

Comment: Aizaz, thanks for your post. I haven't had time to try the solution you posted. Is it working well? As far as I remember, there was no acitivity context but only app context used when I passed any context along.  btw - here's a new blog post on Android on memory analysis: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

Comment: I'm using yourkit.com for mem analysis, also good tool, not free though.